# Cannot log into chat

Tags: empathy

I have set up the chat and broadcast accounts: clicked on my user name on the panel and chose Chat accounts... and Broadcast accounts...
Now when I log into my system I cannot choose my status. In fact it is offline and I cannot choose any of the statuses. If I disable and enable one of them, the status will be online and I can choose any of the statuses. But if I choose offline, then again: I cannot choose any of the statuses.

Comment: which chat client are you using?Empathy or Pidgin?

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't log in'? Are you getting a particular error message? If so, can you please add it to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I figured it out: click on the envelop icon for Empathy and then click on Chat and it will sign all your accounts online.  This really should be automatic, anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a startup application (preferences - startup applications)? Add a new entry running the command line empathy so it fires on startup